# Why does Firebase .onChildAdded.listen() block my database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout, flutter-web

## Summary

In Flutter web, It seems that when I call `.onChildAdded.listen()` on my firebase realtime database connection, that it just stops working. If I uncomment `.onChildAdded.listen()` in `thestate.dart` , database calls work as they should. This is evidenced by the calls I make to directdb inside of `DogApp.widget`. I see nothing in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-guarantees that would indicate this kind of behavior. Would appreciate some insight, thank you.

## Github Code

https://github.com/hunterpp/testdb

You would need to create a realtimedb with an "xyz" doc

## Good Output

This is print output when `.onChildAdded.listen()` is commented out. As you can see, COMPLETE dog 2 is shown, which means that the `directdb` call in `DogApp.widget` is getting data back from the database

```
test doglist
in try doglist
finally doglist
in try getItems
finally getItems
returned
COMPLETE doglist
returned getItems
COMPLETE getItems
test dog 1
in try dog 1
finally dog 1
test dog 2
in try dog 2
finally dog 2
returned
COMPLETE dog 1
returned
COMPLETE dog 2
```

## Bad Output

When `.onChildAdded.listen()` is called, the dog 1 and dog 2 do not execute COMPLETE.
Here

```
test doglist
in try doglist
finally doglist
in try getItems
finally getItems
returned
COMPLETE doglist
returned getItems
COMPLETE getItems
test dog 1
in try dog 1
finally dog 1
test dog 2
in try dog 2
finally dog 2
```

## main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => TheState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
          home: const MyHomePage(
        title: 'ok',
      ))));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var state = Provider.of<TheState>(context, listen: false);
      state.dbInit();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // getting the size of the window
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var height = size.height;
    var width = size.width;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: const SizedBox(height: 500, width: 500, child: DogList())));
  }
}

class DogList extends StatelessWidget {
  const DogList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    directDB("doglist");
    return Consumer<TheState>(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        var nums = state.getItems();
        if (nums == null) {
          return const Text("loading", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
        }
        var prod = List<int>.generate(10, (i) => i + 1);
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                prod
                    .map(
                      (model) => Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: DogApp(model),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class DogApp extends StatelessWidget {
  DogApp(this.num);
  final int num;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    directDB("dog " + num.toString());
    var x = "ok " + num.toString();
    return SizedBox(
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        child: Text(x, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr));
  }
}
```

## thestate.dart

```
final DatabaseReference kDb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

class TheState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int? items;
  Query? _feedQuery;
  Future<bool> dbInit() {
    _feedQuery = kDb.child("page");
    _feedQuery!.onChildAdded.listen(_childAdded);
    initItems();
    return Future.value(true);
  }

  int? getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  void initItems() {
    var calledFrom = "getItems";
    try {
      print("in try" + " " + calledFrom);
      kDb.child('page').once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
        print("returned" + " " + calledFrom);
        final snapshot = event.snapshot;
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var map = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
          items = 5;
          notifyListeners();
        }
      }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
        print("in catchError" + " " + calledFrom);
      }).whenComplete(() => print("COMPLETE" + " " + calledFrom));
    } catch (error) {
      print("catch" + " " + calledFrom);
    } finally {
      print("finally" + " " + calledFrom);
    }
  }

  void _childAdded(DatabaseEvent event) {}
}
```

## directdb.dart

```
void directDB(String calledFrom) {
  print("test" + " " + calledFrom);

  //FirebaseDatabase fd = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  //fd.setLoggingEnabled(true);
  //DatabaseReference dr = fd.ref();
  try {
    print("in try" + " " + calledFrom);
    kDb.child('page').child("xyz").once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
      print("returned");
      final snapshot = event.snapshot;
      if (snapshot.value != null) {
        var map = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
      }
    }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
      print("in catchError" + " " + calledFrom);
    }).whenComplete(() => print("COMPLETE" + " " + calledFrom));
  } catch (error) {
    print("catch" + " " + calledFrom);
  } finally {
    print("finally" + " " + calledFrom);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell if `returned getItems` is being printed to console before `COMPLETE getItems`

Comment: Hi @Jain I have updated the output to the full output. Thank you